# SDL include not working even after using: "#include <SDL2/SDL.h>"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, sdl

after using the following inlcudes and make file:

all:
g++ -IC:\Users\Caleb\SDLTemplate\ -l src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

with this include        #include <SDL2/SDL.h>

its keeps saying:

PS C:\Users\Caleb\Desktop\SDLTemplate> g++ -IC:\Users\Caleb\SDLTemplate\ -l src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
main.cpp:2:22: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
^
compilation terminated.

I tried looking for answers but they all just suggest using #inlcude<SDL2/SDL.h>

Comment: Does `C:\Users\Caleb\SDLTemplate\SDL2\SDL.h` exist? Since this is the include path you added.

Comment: yes it does exist because thats the path that I get from copying where it comes from. I really cant find any answers' that dont already use something that Ive tried I need hlp

Comment: I will literally give someone remote acess to my computer i dont understand how to fix this

Comment: Link pictures of your `C:\Users\Caleb\SDLTemplate` and `C:\Users\Caleb\SDLTemplate\SDL2` folders.